# Reduce computational time of several do loops to compute a sum

Tags: for-loop, fortran

I would like to compute the following sum in Fortran90:

\sum_{i,j,l,t} L_{a,i,j}L{a,l,t} \sum_k \alpha_k A_{i,k} A_{j,k} A_{l,k} A_{t,k}

For the last sum, I was thinking to use the function SUM of Fortran in order to obtain a tensor T_{i,j,l,k}.
However, I do not know how to reduce the computational time for the rest of my sum.
Here it is the version of my loops ignoring the index a at this stage.

```
    tot=0
    do i=1,n
        do j=1,n
           do l=1,n
             do t=1,n
                C1(i,j,l,t)=L(i,j)*L(l,t)*T(i,j,l,t)
                tot=tot+L(i,j)*L(l,t)*T(i,j,l,t)
             end 
          end
        end
     end
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your maths correctly (please confirm!) you can make it much faster by recognising you can rewrite it in terms of matrix multiplies and traces, and totally avoid that 4D tensor. I'll try to explain how here, but given stackoverflow for some stupid reason doesn't seem to support MathJax it might not be very clear ... Anyway given evaluating the 4D tensor must be at least O(N^4), here it is in fact O(N^5), and a matrix multiply is O(N^3) the latter must be a better way to go if you can use it.

Writing

```
S=\sum_{i,j,l,t} L_{i,j}L_{l,t} \sum_k \alpha_k A_{i,k} A_{j,k} A_{l,k} A_{t,k}
```

Taking the k sum outside and grouping together those terms in sums over i, j and separately those in sums over l, k gives

```
S=\sum_k \alpha_k [\sum_{i}A_{i,k}\sum_{j}L_{i,j}A_{j,k}][\sum_{l}A_{l,k}\sum_{t}L_{l,t}A_{t,k}]
```

The terms in square brackets are identical, only the summation indices have changed. Thus writing

```
C_{k}=\sum_{l}A_{l,k}\sum_{t}L_{l,t}A_{t,k}
S=\sum_k \alpha_k C_{k}*C_{k}
```

Examining the form of C we can see we can write the sum over t as a matrix multiply hence

```
B=L*A
C_{k}=\sum_{l}A_{l,k}B_{l,k}
```

Thus our recipe is

1. Form **B** by Matmul( **L**, **A** )
2. Generate C(k)
3. Form the final sum

The code is also much simpler:

```
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ cat tense.f90
Program tense
  
  Use, Intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, Only : wp => real64, li => int64

  Implicit None

  Integer, Parameter :: n = 100

  Real( wp ), Dimension( 1:n, 1:n ) :: a, l

  Real( wp ), Dimension( 1:n, 1:n, 1:n, 1:n ) :: t

  Real( wp ), Dimension( 1:n, 1:n ) :: b

  Real( wp ), Dimension( 1:n ) :: c
  Real( wp ), Dimension( 1:n ) :: alpha

  Real( wp ) :: s
  
  Integer( li ) :: start, finish, rate

  Integer :: i, j, k, p, q

  ! Give A, L values
  Call Random_number( a )
  Call Random_number( l )
  ! Try to avoid huge range of numbers
  a = a - 0.5_wp
  l = l - 0.5_wp

  ! Set alpha all to unity so can compare easily
  alpha = 1.0_wp
  
  ! Method in original post
  Call system_clock( start, rate )
  ! Set up T
  t = 0.0_wp
  Do k = 1, n
     Do q = 1, n
        Do p = 1, n
           Do j = 1, n
              Do i = 1, n
                 t( i, j, p, q ) = t( i, j, p, q ) + &
                      a( i, k ) * a( j, k ) * a( p, k ) * a( q, k )
              End Do
           End Do
        End Do
     End Do
  End Do
  ! Sum
  s = 0.0_wp
  Do q = 1, n
     Do p = 1, n
        Do j = 1, n
           Do i = 1, n
              s = s + L( i, j ) * L( p, q ) * t( i, j, p, q ) 
           End Do
        End Do
     End Do
  End Do
  Call system_clock( finish, rate )
  Write( *, * ) 'Tensor method       : Sum, time ', s, Real( finish - start, wp ) / rate

  ! Matrix factorisation method
  Call system_clock( start, rate )
  b = Matmul( l, a )
  Do k = 1, n
     c( k ) = Sum( a( :, k ) * b( :, k ) )
  End Do
  s = Sum( alpha * c * c )
  Call system_clock( finish, rate )
  Write( *, * ) 'Factorisation method: Sum, time ', s, Real( finish - start, wp ) / rate
  
End Program tense
```

The compilation and running:

```
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

ian@eris:~/work/stack$ gfortran -O3 -std=f2008 -Wall -Wextra tense.f90
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
 Tensor method       : Sum, time    544.08976066804723        14.874410230000001     
 Factorisation method: Sum, time    544.08976066799494        2.4018499999999999E-004
```

So I make that about 60000 time faster for n = 100, and this difference will increase with increasing n. Thinking carefully about the best algorithm always trumps implementation tweaks!

Comment: Am I missing a remark about the fact that Fortran is column major?

Comment: No - thought about it but the proposed method of solution in the question had much more important problems to address. I haven't even mentioned the massive but unnecessary use of memory, which I would rank well before column major - if a program takes too much memory you can't solve the problem fullstop, if it is slow you just have to wait a bit longer.

Comment: That is for sure true, but OP used the row major indices, probably because she was unaware of the fact that Fortran is column major, hence my comment (you use in your solution also the column major order).

Comment: It appears like L and T are arrays. and it appears like l and t are  index variables. This could prose some problems in spite of the case being upper and lower??

Comment: In the Maths yes, and yes it is not the best choice and I might go back and fix that. In the code, no - I use i, j, k, p and q for indices, thus there is no problem